# errors related to ModelMapping when using @ManyToOne

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

User Entity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private int age;
    private String fullName;
    private String address;
    private String phoneNumber;

    @CreationTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "created_by_id")
    private User createdBy;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "updated_by_id")
    private User updatedBy;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "deleted_by_id")
    private User deletedBy;

    @Column(name = "is_deleted")
    private boolean isDeleted = false;

    private LocalDateTime deletedAt;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
    private Company company;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "users_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "roles_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();

    @PrePersist
    private void setRandomId() {
        this.id = generateId();
    }

    private String generateId() {
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }
}
```

JwtUserInfo

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class JwtUserInfo {
    private String id;
    private String fullName;
    private String email;
}
```

UserInfoDto

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserInfoDto {
    private String id;

    @Email(message = "Email must be valid")
    @NotEmpty(message = "Email must not be empty")
    private String email;
    private String fullName;
    private String address;
    private int age;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Phone number must not be empty")
    private String phoneNumber;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Company must not be empty")
    private CompanyInfoDto company;
    private JwtUserInfo createdBy;
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
    private JwtUserInfo updatedBy;
    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;
    private JwtUserInfo deletedBy;
    private LocalDateTime deletedAt;
    private boolean isDeleted;
}
```

Here is a part of my logic for retrieving a user by ID.

```
@Override
    public UserInfoDto getUserById(String id) {
        try {
            User user = userRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(
                    () -> new ResourceNotFoundException("id", "User", id)
            );
            return modelMapper.map(user, UserInfoDto.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

I am encountering an issue where, after logging in and checking the 'getUserById' request in Postman, all IDs return correct results except for when I send a request with the ID 'c65df504-5394-4a10-b2c1-9efecf4b7fbb, which results in an error.

Here is the information in the database that I have converted to JSON for the ID '0843c5b6-1537-4dbf-b8c7-a28cee8a277b'

```
{
    "id": "0843c5b6-1537-4dbf-b8c7-a28cee8a277b",
    "email": "nguyenduongchanhtay@gmail.com",
    "fullName": null,
    "address": "Hanoi",
    "age": 25,
    "phoneNumber": "1241",
    "company": {
        "id": "974818d2-5257-4af9-a83d-0eed14127607",
        "name": "MISA Software"
    },
    "createdBy": {
        "id": "c65df504-5394-4a10-b2c1-9efecf4b7fbb",
        "fullName": "Frankie Nguyen",
        "email": "admin@gmail.com"
    },
    "createdAt": "2023-12-02T03:27:55.736432",
    "updatedBy": null,
    "updatedAt": "2023-12-02T04:18:45.977473",
    "deletedBy": {
        "id": "c65df504-5394-4a10-b2c1-9efecf4b7fbb",
        "fullName": "Frankie Nguyen",
        "email": "admin@gmail.com"
    },
    "deletedAt": "2023-12-02T04:18:45.97672",
    "deleted": true
}
```

Here is the information in the database that I have converted to JSON for the ID 'c65df504-5394-4a10-b2c1-9efecf4b7fbb'

```
{
    "id": "c65df504-5394-4a10-b2c1-9efecf4b7fbb",
    "email": "admin@gmail.com",
    "fullName": "Frankie Nguyen",
    "address": "Hanoi",
    "age": 26,
    "phoneNumber": "123",
    "roles": [
        {
            "id": "f3c11adb-1bfd-495f-9d9d-ce161ce01211",
            "name": "ROLE_USER",
            "permissions": [
                {
                    "id": "733416fd-397f-41c7-bd1d-b76b97dbafaf",
                    "name": "GET_USERS",
                    "module": "USERS",
                    "path": "/users",
                    "method": "GET",
                    "createdBy": {
                        "id": "c65df504-5394-4a10-b2c1-9efecf4b7fbb",
                        "fullName": "Frankie Nguyen",
                        "email": "admin@gmail.com"
                    },
                    "createdAt": "2023-12-04T01:48:21.631549",
                    "updatedBy": null,
                    "updatedAt": "2023-12-04T01:48:21.63157",
                    "deletedBy": null,
                    "deletedAt": null,
                    "deleted": false
                },
                {
                    "id": "c4a6f052-0753-44db-ac4c-be92711453a4",
                    "name": "GET_USER_BY_ID",
                    "module": "USERS",
                    "path": "/users/{id}",
                    "method": "GET",
                    "createdBy": {
                        "id": "c65df504-5394-4a10-b2c1-9efecf4b7fbb",
                        "fullName": "Frankie Nguyen",
                        "email": "admin@gmail.com"
                    },
                    "createdAt": "2023-12-02T19:30:58.923667",
                    "updatedBy": null,
                    "updatedAt": "2023-12-02T19:30:58.923703",
                    "deletedBy": null,
                    "deletedAt": null,
                    "deleted": false
                },
                {
                    "id": "00140d2d-f596-4a01-841b-c1b62abb72d7",
                    "name": "UPDATE_USER_BY_ID",
                    "module": "USERS",
                    "path": "/users/{id}",
                    "method": "PATCH",
                    "createdBy": {
                        "id": "c65df504-5394-4a10-b2c1-9efecf4b7fbb",
                        "fullName": "Frankie Nguyen",
                        "email": "admin@gmail.com"
                    },
                    "createdAt": "2023-12-02T19:31:28.028948",
                    "updatedBy": null,
                    "updatedAt": "2023-12-02T19:31:28.028996",
                    "deletedBy": null,
                    "deletedAt": null,
                    "deleted": false
                },
                {
                    "id": "fada1727-d13e-48e5-81bf-3d8d52c24e93",
                    "name": "GET_COMPANIES",
                    "module": "COMPANIES",
                    "path": "/companies",
                    "method": "GET",
                    "createdBy": {
                        "id": "c65df504-5394-4a10-b2c1-9efecf4b7fbb",
                        "fullName": "Frankie Nguyen",
                        "email": "admin@gmail.com"
                    },
                    "createdAt": "2023-12-02T19:34:11.256933",
                    "updatedBy": null,
                    "updatedAt": "2023-12-02T19:34:11.25695",
                    "deletedBy": null,
                    "deletedAt": null,
                    "deleted": false
                },
                {
                    "id": "88b80919-5903-4f0b-baa9-3cfce16e7724",
                    "name": "GET_COMPANY_BY_ID",
                    "module": "COMPANIES",
                    "path": "/companies/{id}",
                    "method": "GET",
                    "createdBy": {
                        "id": "c65df504-5394-4a10-b2c1-9efecf4b7fbb",
                        "fullName": "Frankie Nguyen",
                        "email": "admin@gmail.com"
                    },
                    "createdAt": "2023-12-02T19:34:28.031876",
                    "updatedBy": null,
                    "updatedAt": "2023-12-02T19:34:28.03191",
                    "deletedBy": null,
                    "deletedAt": null,
                    "deleted": false
                }
            ],
            "createdBy": {
                "id": "c65df504-5394-4a10-b2c1-9efecf4b7fbb",
                "fullName": "Frankie Nguyen",
                "email": "admin@gmail.com"
            },
            "createdAt": "2023-12-03T04:21:52.351181",
            "updatedBy": {
                "id": "c65df504-5394-4a10-b2c1-9efecf4b7fbb",
                "fullName": "Frankie Nguyen",
                "email": "admin@gmail.com"
            },
            "updatedAt": "2023-12-04T04:07:11.08364",
            "deletedBy": null,
            "deletedAt": null,
            "active": false,
            "deleted": false
        }
    ],
    "createdBy": null,
    "createdAt": "2023-12-01 02:31:17.460545",
    "updatedBy": {
        "id": "c65df504-5394-4a10-b2c1-9efecf4b7fbb",
        "fullName": "Frankie Nguyen",
        "email": "admin@gmail.com"
    },
    "updatedAt": "2023-12-04T22:39:23.040448",
    "deletedBy": null,
    "deletedAt": null,
    "deleted": false
}
```

When I send a 'getUserById' request with the ID '0843c5b6-1537-4dbf-b8c7-a28cee8a277b', the response returns the information in the database that I previously converted to JSON above.
But when I send a request with the ID 'c65df504-5394-4a10-b2c1-9efecf4b7fbb', it encounters an error as shown in the image below.

```
{
    "timestamp": "2023-12-05T00:45:46.731086",
    "message": "ModelMapper mapping errors:\n\n1) Error mapping com.frankie.workdev.entity.User to com.frankie.workdev.dto.user.UserInfoDto\n\n1 error",
    "details": "uri=/api/v1/users/c65df504-5394-4a10-b2c1-9efecf4b7fbb",
    "errorCode": "BAD_REQUEST"
}
```

This is the error log within the catch block in IntelliJ.

```
org.modelmapper.MappingException: ModelMapper mapping errors:

1) Error mapping com.frankie.workdev.entity.User to com.frankie.workdev.dto.user.UserInfoDto

1 error
    at org.modelmapper.internal.Errors.throwMappingExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:380)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.map(MappingEngineImpl.java:80)
    at org.modelmapper.ModelMapper.mapInternal(ModelMapper.java:573)
    at org.modelmapper.ModelMapper.map(ModelMapper.java:406)
    at com.frankie.workdev.service.serviceImpl.UserServiceImpl.getUserById(UserServiceImpl.java:121)
    at com.frankie.workdev.controller.UserController.getUserById(UserController.java:41)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:254)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:182)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:917)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:829)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.lambda$doFilterInternal$3(FilterChainProxy.java:231)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:365)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:131)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:181)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at com.frankie.workdev.security.JwtAuthFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
Caused by: org.modelmapper.MappingException: ModelMapper mapping errors:

1) Failed to set value 'com.frankie.workdev.dto.user.UserInfoDto@1dfba458' on com.frankie.workdev.dto.user.UserInfoDto.setUpdatedBy()

1 error
    at org.modelmapper.internal.Errors.toMappingException(Errors.java:258)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.PropertyInfoImpl$MethodMutator.setValue(PropertyInfoImpl.java:126)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingContextImpl.getParentDestination(MappingContextImpl.java:325)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.setDestinationValue(MappingEngineImpl.java:230)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.propertyMap(MappingEngineImpl.java:187)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.typeMap(MappingEngineImpl.java:151)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.map(MappingEngineImpl.java:114)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.map(MappingEngineImpl.java:71)
    ... 102 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:108)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.PropertyInfoImpl$MethodMutator.setValue(PropertyInfoImpl.java:124)
    ... 108 more
```

I have looked into the information and found that using @ManyToOne may cause errors when mapping an object with a self-referencing relationship. However, my logic is to have one user create multiple accounts, but each account belongs to only one user in fields such as createdBy, updatedBy, and deletedBy. I hope someone can provide guidance on this matter. Thank you.

Comment: By looking into the exception, seems `ModelMapper` trying to insert `UserInfoDto` type to `updatedBy` property by calling `UserInfoDto.setUpdatedBy()`, but based on your `UserInfoDto` class definition it accepts `JwtUserInfo` type. That's why you are getting `argument type mismatch` error message. In my opinion why `0843c5b6-1537-4dbf-b8c7-a28cee8a277b` is successful, because it's returning `NULL` for `updatedBy` property. So, there is no conversion issue. Can you ads the `updatedBy` data for `0843c5b6-1537-4dbf-b8c7-a28cee8a277b` and try

Comment: can you share what version of `ModelMapper` and `Java` along with provider like `oracle-jdk`, `open-jdk`, `zulu`, etc., you are using